# Calculating Rin of a differential amplifier

Tags: pspice, differential-amplifier

I have this circuit:

[image]

I want to find the input impedance \$R_in\$ with a PSPICE simulation. I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: If Vin and Iin are in phase, then Rin = Vin / Iin. Otherwise Rin = Vin / Iin * cos(theta)  where theta is the phase difference between Vin and Iin. Cos (theta)  is also known as the power factor. The complex impedance has a magnitude of Vin / Iin and its angle is theta.

Comment: Do an **AC Analysis** and just calculate  Zin= v(Vin) / i(C1) if you use a capacitor at input. So, you get the input complex impedance versus frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do an AC Analysis;
Just calculate \$Zin= v(Vin) / i(C1)\$

[image]

Made with microcap v12, [spectrum-soft](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/mc12cd.zip).